# Did Azure Blob Storage Library Change?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I've been using WindowsAzure.Storage 8.* library to work with a container to move some blobs around. Recently, I wanted to get a list of blobs using the the below code from the example on the Microsoft site.  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs#set-up-your-development-environment)  When I attempted to use the 'ListBlobs()', the method is no longer available via the library.  I was using this in console apps whereas now I'm attempting to use this in a .net core web application.  Is there a different approach to get a list of blobs in different environments?  I'm just not sure why the method is not available in the same namespace/library/version...?

```
// Retrieve storage account from connection string.
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

// Create the blob client.
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

// Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("photos");

// Loop over items within the container and output the length and URI.
foreach (IListBlobItem item in container.ListBlobs(null, false))
{
if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
{
    CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;

    Console.WriteLine("Block blob of length {0}: {1}",    blob.Properties.Length, blob.Uri);

}
else if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudPageBlob))
{
    CloudPageBlob pageBlob = (CloudPageBlob)item;

    Console.WriteLine("Page blob of length {0}: {1}", pageBlob.Properties.Length, pageBlob.Uri);

}
else if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlobDirectory))
{
    CloudBlobDirectory directory = (CloudBlobDirectory)item;

    Console.WriteLine("Directory: {0}", directory.Uri);
}
}
```

Comment: Does it still works for your console app? (not .net core version)?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio yes.

Comment: I think it's a bug related to .net core version. I recommend you open an issue directly on Github. https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net

Comment: maybe I'm wrong but the github page does't say that it supports .NET core yet.

Comment: if you are moving to Azure.Storage namespaces this page is the most helpful thing I've found https://www.craftedforeveryone.com/beginners-guide-and-reference-to-azure-blob-storage-sdk-v12-dot-net-csharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this question: [Missing syncronous methods for dotnet core?](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/367)，NetCore/Netstandard support does not yet include Sync implementation of the APIs.

Since ListBlobs is a synchronous method and therefore is missing on platforms that do not support synchronous methods, so you cloud only call ListBlobsSegmentedAsync and handle the continuation token it returns.

More details about how to use ListBlobsSegmentedAsync to list the blob, you could refer to follow link’s example:
[CloudBlobClient.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobclient.listblobssegmentedasync.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. I accepted your answer because the async method works.  But I do use non-async methods within .net core so I'm not sure if this 'therefore is missing on platforms that do not support synchronous methods' entirely makes sense to me.

Comment: I agree with you, what I mean is .net core now isn't support the Sync implementation of the APIs, so we couldn't use the ListBlobs method or table.execute(tablequery) and so on.

Answer (score 1):

From 9.4.2 SDK, Microsoft has brought back the sync implementations: 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/tree/master/Blob

Answer (score 0):

As Brando said they brought the synchronous methods back in that SDK but its now deprecated.

...use [Azure Storage Blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage.blobs-readme?view=azure-dotnet)